# reCAPTCHA is not shown correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, firebug, recaptcha, osclass

I've enabled the reCAPTCHA in my osclass.org site.

The image is not in the captcha. What's wrong in the code? I've test it with firebug - but I don't find an error.

Could someone give me a hint? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I've found the error: osclass.org put a custom recaptcha in this site. I've tried to use the white recaptcha. Both at the same time...